# What should be done if an answer becomes outdated?

Tags: discussion

Assume a question is asked and has a high-quality answer (or several).  Then, over time, the answers become less useful (or even obsolete) due to new versions of languages or (more frequent) more recent versions of software.

What is the best way to proceed?  I am currently leaning towards leaving a comment for the old answer and writing a new one, with a heading "Update for foobar version x.y".

Comment: Relevant from MetaSE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11705/248731

Answer (score -1):

The question and/or answer should be edited to reflect the versions relevant to them.  If a question is asked about a specific version, the relevant tag for that version should be there, and possibly mentioned in the question itself if it's not already there.

If the question is intentionally written to be not specific to a particular version, but an answer was written to only applies to a particular version, then it would be okay to indicate that in the answer.

If you have a new solution to a problem using a new version of a product, you're more than welcome to post a new answer, if the question isn't specifying an earlier version.  It is *not* appropriate to edit in your entirely new solution into someone else's answer though.  If the question itself is tied to a specific older version then you can ask a new question about doing that task in the newer version of the product and self-answer it.  Note that, when self answering, keep in mind that both the question and answer will be evaluated for quality independently, and each should stand on their own as a quality post.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest two approaches, depending on how out-of-date the old answer is:

1. If there are minor changes due to version updates (attribute names changed, slightly different behaviour, some additional caveats) I would suggest editing the existing answer, highlighting where (and from which version) the updates apply; or
2. For more significant changes (e.g. a completely new way of doing things that didn't previously exist) adding a new answer and either commenting on or editing the old answer to clarify the relevant versions is probably the best approach (see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/10166574/3001761).